# Not able to view chat transcripts in chatbase

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbase

I integrated a Dialogflow agent with chatbase. I can view all the metrics in the chatbase portal except for the chat transcripts. I checked the request body and all the parameters including the user and agent messages are being passed. I get "Unable to load the transcripts. Please try refreshing the page." message when clicking on View Transcripts. What could be the issue?